# Вопрос по массивам

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть структура (`dadaInt`), которая содержит ссылку на массив чисел и размер.

Есть функция (`init`) в которой есть массив который добавляется в структуру.

Проблема в том что массив (`data_[]`) перезаписывается после завершения функции.

Результат вывода:

```
3
-858993460
11870055
5633636
1370782638
1371061128
```

Какие есть способы решение этой проблемы? (не надо предлагать `static`)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct dadaInt
{
    int* data;
    int size;
};

void init(dadaInt &dadaInt_)
{

    int data_[] = { 3,2,3,4,5,6 };
    int size_ = sizeof(data_) / sizeof(data_[0]);

    dadaInt_.data = data_;
    dadaInt_.size = size_;

}

int main()
{
    dadaInt data;

    init(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << data.data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: То, что вы представили, не имеет никакого смысла.  Лучше опишите то задание, которые вам надо сделать, и в связи с которым появился этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

```
void init(dadaInt &dadaInt_)
{

    int data_[] = { 3,2,3,4,5,6 };
    int size_ = sizeof(data_) / sizeof(data_[0]);

    dadaInt_.data = data_;
    dadaInt_.size = size_;

}
```

Вы присваиваете указатель на **локальный** массив `data_`, который после выхода из функции исчезает. И вы получаете указатель на непонятно какой мусор, только и всего...

Решение - выделение массива динамически.

```
void init(dadaInt &dadaInt_)
{

    dadaInt_.data = new int[6]{3,2,3,4,5,6 };
    dadaInt_.size = 6;

}
```

Только потом не забудьте освобождать память. Например, написав деструктор...

Comment: это не сработает если массив получаю из файла. динамически пока что лучший вариант но и у него есть недостаток если массив из миллиона переменных с плавающей точкой. За ответ спасибо.

Comment: А какая разница - если миллион переменных? Что, в стеке это было бы чем-то лучше?...